# Identity command is failing for pdf and txt files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imagemagick, paperclip, identity

For some reason tests fail for pdf and txt files, however using the app through the browser I am able to upload both of these formats.

Any ideas for how to fix this?

Error that is thrown:

```
Image /tmp/stream20110105-27382-hc9w7l-0.pdf is not recognized by the 'identify' command..
```

Output of identify command calls:

```
# png file works
[chris@chris-archlinux test]$ identify fixtures/files/brown-1920x1080.png fixtures/files/brown-1920x1080.png PNG 1920x1080 1920x1080+0+0 8-bit DirectClass 257KB 0.000u 0:00.000

# jpg works
[chris@chris-archlinux test]$ identify fixtures/files/avatar.jpg fixtures/files/avatar.jpg JPEG 478x478 478x478+0+0 8-bit DirectClass 72KB 0.000u 0:00.000

# txt fails
[chris@chris-archlinux test]$ identify fixtures/files/file_2.txt identify: unable to read font `/usr/share/fonts/Type1/n019003l.pfb' @ error/annotate.c/RenderFreetype/1059. identify: no decode delegate for this image format `/tmp/magick-XXKkKcoe' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/532. identify: unable to get type metrics `fixtures/files/file_2.txt' @ error/txt.c/ReadTEXTImage/256.

# pdf fails
[chris@chris-archlinux test]$ identify fixtures/files/file.pdf identify: no decode delegate for this image format `fixtures/files/file.pdf' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/532.
```

Answer (score 0):

**Are you using Paperclip for attachments? If so, read on. Otherwise ignore...**

I remember having a similar error when trying to use Paperclip. It was because my executable path wasn't setup right. Assuming you have all the imagemagick binaries installed, try adding the following to an initialize or environment file:

My OS X env uses:

```
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/local/bin"
```

Linux env uses:

```
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/bin"
```

Comment: I am using paperclip. I had already tried that as well as creating symlinks from the usr/local/bin/identity to /usr/bin/identity to prevent breakage on macs.  The issue is that identity seems to work fine for pdf and jpgs in the tests; just not for pdf and txt files.

Comment: Are you actually linking the command_path to /usr/bin/identify as you stated, or just using /usr/bin as shown in my example?

Comment: I have tried them both and neither of them work, but as I mentioned I can't take the config route since it would break things for mac users.

Comment: I am a mac user but I don't understand what would be breaking though.

Comment: It seems we are running around in circles :) If I change the command path, will it still work for people using macs?  If so then I guess it doesn't break anything.  However, it's irrelevant since it doesn't fix my problem.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
pacman -S ghostscript
```

As root.  That ought to fix your pdf problem, at least.